# I am trying to add post to my blog post but when i added this the <p> tag appears also in my blog

Tags: laravel

In the blog code :

```
<div class="blog-inner">
                    <h4><a href="blog-single.html">{{$post->title}}</a></h4>
                        {{$post->content}}
                    <div class="meta">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i><a href="#">{{$post->slug}}</a></span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>{{$post->created_at}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

In the CreateBlog :

```
<div class="font-medium flex items-center border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-dark-5 pb-5"> <i data-feather="chevron-down" class="w-4 h-4 mr-2"></i><label for="content-tab">Text Content</label> </div>
                                        <div class="mt-5" >
                                            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="editor"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5h71.png)

Comment: use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```php
{!! $post->content !!}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous...

Answer (score 0):

By default you would use the following syntax `{{ $some_variable }}` to echo out the content of a specific variable in Blade. By default the `{{ }}` escapes the HTML tags.

So let's say that you have a blog post with a `$post` collection which has some HTML elements in the body property

If you were to use the following:

```
<div>{{ $post->body }}</div>
```

all of the HTML tags would not be rendered as HTML, but plain text.

If you don't want your HTML tags to be escaped then you should use `{!! !!}`

```
<div>{!! $post->body !!}</div>
```